# Select limited number of records for each group variation

Tags: sql, oracle

Each record contains `RecordID, TypeID, GroupID`.
There are many records to a `Type` and many types to a `Group`.
I want to return 3 records for each combination of type and group.

Any suggestions?

*simplified output like this*

```
Group | Type | Record
------+------+--------
1     | 1    | 1
1     | 1    | 2
1     | 1    | 3
1     | 2    | 1
1     | 2    | 2
1     | 2    | 3
1     | 3    | 1
....
9     | 1    | 1
9     | 2    | 2
etc..
```

This is the solution that worked for me, a variation of the answer given.

It is code for a migration, so absolute optimisation is not necessary - but appreciate further pointers.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT RecordId
    FROM (
      SELECT RecordId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId, TypeId ORDER BY RecordId) As seq FROM yourTable) t2
      WHERE seq <= 3 AND t2.RecordId = t1.RecordId
    )
ORDER BY GroupId, TypeId
```

Comment: Short of doing some loops, I've been reading up on 'possible solutions'  - some here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group - a lot of overcomplicated looking queries and terms i'm unfamiliar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId, TypeId ORDER BY RecordId) As seq
    FROM yourTable) dt
WHERE seq <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks clean - I will try to troubleshoot it. Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: This query runs fine if I replace the * for some actual fields - I could use a select * from table where IN those results - or something, will post when I get it. Thanks

Comment: I added the final solution to my original post, thank you for getting me there.